# Power Bi using "IN" in Dax

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am posting this here but I am having issues to post in Power BI community (for some reason keeps giving me errors when I post the question).

I am trying to get the total Previous Sales  basedbut on certain conditions,  I keep getting and error when I add `IN` to the formula:

```
PrevTotalSales =
Var prev = selectedvalue(sales(previousperiod)
RETURN 
CALCULATE ( 
COUNTA(Sales[SaleNbr]),(Sales[period]=prev), sales[code] in ("a","b","c")
)
```

Any suggestions? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use curly brackets `{`,`}` instead of parenthesis `(`,`)` for your list.

Your variable row also has issues, but this should fix your `IN` problem.

Answer (score 0):

[This seems to be the answer you need](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/IN-OPERATOR-in-PowerBi/td-p/174285).

Basically, instead of using `Var in Var_List` you need to change it to `if List.Contains({Var_List},[Var]) then`

Comment: No. `List.Contains` is M language, and will not work in a DAX measure.